# Normalizr is not processing data in envelope

Tags: javascript, redux, normalizr

I am using normalizr for data that I receive from Api. When I am receiving list I get normalized entities as expected.

But when I send request that updates one entity, I am receiving only one entity wrapped in data envelope witch is not processed by normalizr correctly.

```
// Normalize setting
import { Schema, arrayOf } from 'normalizr'

export const player = new Schema('players')
export const arrayOfPlayers = arrayOf(player)

//This is what I use for normalize 
response => normalize(response, {players: schema.player})
```

And I am receiving data like following with only one player in the list:

```
{
    code: 200,
    message: '',
    data: { 
        players: [{
            id: 20
            username: 'Gamer'
        }]
    }
}
```

What I should change to retrieve player as normalized entity?

**update:**

Example of Api call.

```
  fetch(
    url,
    { credentials: 'include' }
  )
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => normalize(response, {players: schema.player})) 
    .then( // dispatch redux action )
    .catch(function (error) {
    })
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the api call?

Comment: Uneducated guess: `normalize(response.data, …)` or `normalize(response, {data: {players: …}})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**if you receive array you should use arrayOf ,otherwise refer to object through res.data.players[0]**

change this

```
normalize(response, {players: schema.player} )
```

to:

**1)**

```
normalize(response.data, {players: arrayOf(schema.player) })
```

result will be

```
{
    entities: {
        players: {
            20: {
                id: 20,
                username: "Gamer"
            }
        }
    },
    result: {
        players: [
            20
        ]
    }
}
```

**2)**

```
normalize(res.data.players[0], player)
```

result will be

```
{
    entities: {
        players: {
            20: {
                id: 20,
                username: "Gamer"
            }
        }
    },
    result: 20
}
```

**[webpackbin demo test with other options](http://www.webpackbin.com/N1_GJy_uW)**

Comment: Thanks I have used solution 1) with small change maybe it is bad design of api. But the response I am looking for is object on index 0.

normalize(response[0].data, {players: arrayOf(schema.player) })

Comment: The problem was in backend endpoint now I can use normalize(response.data, {players: schema.player} )